# Codeigniter 3 Email not sending

Tags: codeigniter-3

So I have just updated my CI project to version 3. Everything is working great except the emails.

I have created a test function to send emails and i output the debugger and part of the response prints:

Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

I have kept the same configuration file as my CI2 project. Is that alright?

NOTE: This has only been tested on my local environment.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: So I couldnt find a solution for this so I removed the CI3 Email helper from the system files and replaced it with the CI2 version. This seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with CI3.1.0. I'll replace my system file and see if I can get it running again. Thanks for the patch.

Comment: I got it fixed for my project. Apparently the email config file really likes the 'newline' to be set in CI3. Where as it didn't really have to be in CI2. I added $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; and it's working fine. I'll post it as an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: And this works with the CI3 system files. No reason to switch them to the old ones.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

It's so important, and put a real working email, Good luck .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and here's what solved it for me. When you set your config parameters for the email library you must include one for the 'newline' in CI3.

So if your current config looks something like this:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'test@test.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'yourpassword';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype'] = 'text';
```

You need to add:

```
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

Also, see those double quotes? You have to use double quotes on the 'newline' or it won't work.